# "Too many symbol files" in my .ipa but dSYM file is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcodebuild, app-store-connect

I have an issue when I submit my React Native app to apple. I receive a mail report saying that my app has too many symbol files.
I search on internet and found few informations about dwarfdump and dSYM files. The thing is, when I go to my .xcarchive in which I have the dSYM folder, this one does not contains the ID that Apple is reporting to me :

```
ITMS-90381: Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary [BDACE718-2EB9-3A6F-B95B-03C58CC906BA.symbols].
```

In the .xcarchive that correspond to this mail, the dwardfdump show me this :

```
$ dwarfdump --uuid *
UUID: 8242D350-A670-33DC-95CE-83213763BDE3 (arm64) BatchRichNotificationsExtension.appex.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/BatchRichNotificationsExtension
UUID: 00E8D7C8-52B6-3A7C-A4CD-0EE75C95DEFD (armv7) MaterialShowcase.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MaterialShowcase
UUID: E5BD2A99-0506-357E-BF51-99CE2D28429B (arm64) MaterialShowcase.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MaterialShowcase
UUID: C84B7E7D-F434-346B-B754-D3101D7C2771 (armv7) my-app.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/my-app
UUID: 7E873541-92BD-3C82-9F56-14A69642AEF9 (arm64) my-app.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/my-app
```

Here is my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'my-app' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.20.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.20.1'

  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
  pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 7.1.1'
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
  pod 'Batch', '~> 1.13'
  pod 'Amplitude-iOS', '~> 4.0.4'

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
        end
    end
end
```

Is there anywhere else that would allow me to find where is this problematic symbol file and how to remove this file / warning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a similar problem in one of my company's apps.  In our case we have all the dSYMs for the frameworks in armv7 and arm64.  The only exception is the dSYM for the application, which is only in arm64.  Your listing above is similar.  The dSYM for the BatchRichNotificationExtension is missing it's armv7.  This may or may not be the same cause.  I see that your UUIDs for the dSYMs don't match the one in the error.  Good luck!